# link is opened under popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Can anyone give me any idea how can i fix this. i want to show a popup with a link, when i click the link, the tab is opened under popup and i can't see it completelly. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r06Y.png)

Here is the code:

```
var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'Benvenuto!',
    template: 'Questa è la sezione che ti permette di guadagnare, condividendo l’App con tutti i tuoi contatti.' +
    '<br> Più amici effettueranno il download maggiori saranno i tuoi guadagni.' +
    '<br> Affrettati hai 30 giorni!' +
    '<br><br>' +
    '<a ui-sref="regulation">' +
    ' Il regolamento di partecipazione' +
    '</a>',
    okText: 'Annulla',
    okType: 'button-positive',
    cancelText: 'Accettare',
    cancelType: 'button-positive'
    }
);
```

Comment: are you showing the data on clicking the link inside the pop up or on confirming the pop up?

Comment: @ Sa E Chowdary  on clicking the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a ui-sref="regulation"> instead of this use below

<a ng-click="go()">something</a>

$scope.go=funtion(){
   $modalInstance.close() //close your modal 
   $state.go("Your state");
}
```

Comment: but i want to come back to popup, because the link is terms and conditions and i want to accept it, what can u suggest to me?

Comment: but i want to come back to popup, because the link is terms and conditions and i want to accept it, what can u suggest to me? @Pravin Erande

Comment: I don't think so you gotta better way rather than opening terms & conditions in another popup (i.e popup in popup)